# Advanced sorting implementation in ASP.NET by letters, numbers & characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net, webforms

I want to implement some kind of sorting against my records, according to many factors
like name, age...so what I've accomplished so far is creating a User Control to display the factors (Name | City ) from the database
so when I click on "Name" it populates a repeater with all the alphabet plus "Other Characters" to display the names that start with number or other characters
and when click on "City" the repeater is populated with all the cities I have in my database

the city sorting is easy i think, but I'm now I'm working on the name sorting.

Now I hope I'd find help with this points :

1 - As far I implemented, do you think it's a good implementation or not..is it optimum to optimizing the load on the db

---

2 - I used this query "SELECT [id], [name] FROM list WHERE (name like @SearchString + '%' ) and the search string is retrieved from a querystring which equals to the letter I want to order by But how can return all the names that start with numbers or other characters, I mean I don't want to list beside my alphabet list, a list of ALL the characters and numbers :S!

**EDIT for point number 2!**

I've managed to get the "Other" button to successfully filter all records that doesn't start with alphabet ( numers or special characters ) by using this Wildcards format `name like '[^a-z]%'` I hope it'll help other people!

---

3 - I've placed the repeater in the Page.aspx and then bound it to a SqlDataReader object instead of using a SqlDataSource in the code behind file, I thought it would be better to control opening and closing the connection and handle the errors as I one can't know what's going on with the connection while using SqlDataSource!, if I'm wrong please correct me, I just spent 1 month practicing! anyway when I first used SqlDataSource I could easily provide a default value for the parameter so I don't get an error because the display repeater needs to be populated and when first the page loads it's clean with no querystrings but I couldn't find a way now as i'm using some ADO.NET classes and as a datasource for the repeater a SqlDataReader Object

```
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="arrange_by_id" QueryStringField="ID" 
        Type="Int32" DefaultValue="1" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

P.S I thought about RegEx for filtering all the records that start with a number or character, it's like the sql wildcards but way more advances, problem is I don't know if it's even possible to be used in such situation or how to use it within my queries

Comment: It's more than one question, because It will be more clear to explain my case and ask my questions instead of separating the questions and explaning my case or example everytime...my mainly concern is to implement filtering for all the records according to the alphabet (there will be a list with the alphabet ) and just one button which will be used to filter all the records that starts with numbers and special characters!...I've tried to summarize my questions in 3 points

Comment: It's Asp.Net Web Forms, not Asp.net MVC

Comment: ok, it is more than 1 question -- what are the questions?  If your questions are -- am I doing this right?  The only way we can answer is if you show more code -- because your descriptions are not as clear as seeing the code would be.

Comment: I think now we are down to 2 questions!

one of them, is "am I doing this right" but the code will make my question even more complicated, any suggestions on how to share it ?

the second one, is about whether to use SqlDataSource for my repeater or Sql connection, command, and bind it to the reader...aslo i need a default value to be assigned to the repeater when the page first loads (no querystring in the url) I used a default property and posted the sample code already, wish i could find an alternative for it If i want to use SqlDataReader instead of SqlDataSource!

Comment: I know it's complicated :S..thanks for your time, hope it's more clear!

Comment: There are many website which allow for code posting.  I always enjoy https://gist.github.com/ and http://pastebin.com/ check this question for even more options : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6825/useful-code-paste-site-tools

Comment: https://gist.github.com/674412 I use this code for my control, it's function is to populate Repeater1 with all the factors to which I want to sort my records according to (id = 1 = name, id = 2= city) and depending on the id which is passed as a querystring Repeater2 is populated with the items to filter, like when I click on name it retrieves all the alphabet from the database, or when I click on City Repeater2 is populated from database with all the cities...of course I hope to use sqldatareader but I need to figure how to let the repeaters have a default value for their parameters.

Comment: to be clear my question here, am I using a good approach ? I mean everytime a user loads the page it will connect to the database and populate 2 repeaters, and every element he'll choose will reconnect to the database again, I mean he'll click Name, then choose A, then Choose T..every click is a connection to the database...is it normal or I have to make hard code it or use another approach ?

Comment: @IKashef : I have some comments but I have to go to a meeting -- you should modify the original question with these comments so others can see them and jump in if they want.

Comment: Ok sure good luck!...I'll try to read all the comments and rewrite the question to update the people! I think many beginners have very similar questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a standard pattern for using a datareader, I would use this:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(commandString, cn))
  {
     using (SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
     {
        // use dr to read values.
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the use of adding the keyword 'using' ? and do you think it's better to use SqlDataReader than SqlDataObject ?

Comment: The using construct ensures the resources are properly disposed.  I think the objectdatasource is useful if you going to do paging or sorting but you probably want to make a custom objectdatascource to optimize these features.

Comment: Here is a nice example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx   Post code with problems if you have them.

Comment: so the using construct is a substitute for Cn.Open(); and Cn.Close(); and disposal of the reader ?